# Binding socket to a network interface ip transfers data through loopback

Tags: c, linux, networking, network-interface

I'm running some experiments regarding network communication and wrote a simple client-server application using the IP address of a specific network interface. Here is a sample:

`server.c`

```
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
//corresponds to wifi adapter
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("100.100.100.100"); 
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(22222);
int socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
//bind socket to the NI
bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof serv_addr); 
listen(socket_fd, 1);
```

`client.c`

```
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
memset(&serv_addr, '\0', sizeof serv_addr);
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
//corresponds to wifi adapter
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("100.100.100.100"); 
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(22222);
int socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
//bind socket to the NI
bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof serv_addr); 
connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof serv_addr);
```

Here is the `ifconfig` output after running the `client` and `server` on a local laptop once:

```
lo: [...]
        inet 127.0.0.1
        RX packets 73718  bytes 1320101962 (1.3 GB) //<--- Data were received through loopback
        TX packets 73718  bytes 1320101962 (1.3 GB) //<--- Data were transmitted through loopback
        [...]

wirl0: [...]
        inet 100.100.100.100
        RX packets 54020  bytes 61156291 (61.1 MB) //<-- left unchanged after run
        TX packets 25452  bytes 3745001 (3.7 MB)   //<-- left unchanged after run
```

**The Problem:**

Even after binding both client and server to a specific network interface the data were anyway transferred through `lo`. What I want to achieve is the actual `nic` comes into play when transferring data. Is it possible to do?

Comment: I would be mildly surprised if the physical NIC could serve as a physical loopback by itself.  This falls into the category of "why would anyone want to do that?"  It's conceivable that the NIC could relay through the local gateway, but that would be perverse, because every hop in an IP route is supposed to get the message *closer* to its destination, but routing through another device would mean the first step takes the message farther away.  I'm not prepared to say it's impossible, but it's not the way networking is supposed to work.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Regarding the "Why" I'd like to benchmark the bandwith of the nic when transferring raw data. Sort of how much data the driver itself can handle per timeunit.

Comment: @SomeName Even if kernel did show those local traffic numbers on wireless interface, would that answer to the question "How much data can wireless driver handle"? I think not.

Comment: @ErkiAring Don't understand the reason why not? From my understanding how it should work the driver should send some packets to router that would redirect them back to the origin.

Comment: @SomeName ok, in this case you are measuring overall network speed, not the amount of data the driver (I mean wireless driver in kernel) can handle.